# In .Net Core what happens a request in an api if the caller times out / closes the connection?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I currently have a restful api created using .Net Core. A third party can call my api and some additional calls are made from my api before returning a response.

In the situation that third parties request timeout / they cancel the request, what happens the request within the .net core api. Will it continue to stay alive and return a response or will the thread  / call stop?

If it will stop, how can I ensure than this does not happen?

Comment: An HTTP request has no state so it can't be cancelled. That holds for *any* web server or stack, not just ASP.NET Core. The *server* has no way of knowing if the original client is still up. I say "original" because an HTTP request can go through multiple proxies and firewalls before it reaches the server.

Comment: So in this case the request would continue even if the caller timed out and there would be no error when the request tries to return a response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your implementation.

You can inject a `CancellationToken` to each controller endpoint and use it, to check whether a request has been canceled or not.

By default, when the browser cancels a request, that information is received from the server and the cancellation is being requested. The flag `RequestAborted` is then being set on the `HttpContext` available in each request or via the `IHttpContextAccessor` outside of controller endpoints.

Prior ASP.NET Core 2.0 there was a problem when using IIS as a reverse-proxy. It wouldn't recognize the cancellation of a request.

Some resources:

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/09/12/cancellationtokens-and-aborted-asp-net-core-requests.aspx

https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

https://dev.to/joaofbantunes/using-cancellation-tokens-on-aspnet-core-mvc-actions-57hi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestaborted?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: So I dont want to cancel any requests. Looking at the Andrew Lock link you provided, it seems if the request is cancelled the api will continue with the request. This is what I was looking to confirm and the functionality I wanted. This will allow me to cache the response on my api. Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. You don't cancel it yourself, but when the user does cancel the request, for whatever reason, the API is being notified when injecting the `CancellationToken` in your API endpoint.